# Applescript Mojave Click Image Capture Button

Tags: button, applescript

How does Applescript click button "Delete" in Mojave Image Capture?

In ML, this works --

```
activate application "Image Capture"
tell application "System Events"
    click button 3 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Image Capture" of application process "Image Capture" of application "System Events"
end tell
```

-- and I have not yet got the equivalent for Mojave. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

They moved things around a little.  Try this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Image Capture"
        set frontmost to true
        click window "Image Capture"'s splitter group 1's group 2's button "Delete"
        key code 48 -- tab to move focus to 'delete'
        -- key code 36 -- return key
    end tell
end tell
```

I added code that clears the "Are you sure?" dialog and automatically deletes the image, but I commented out the 'key code 36' line, which simulates a return key, because I didn't want you to accidentally delete something important.

**Debugging GUI scripting**

if the above code throws an error, and you don't have UIElementExplorer or UIBrowser (apps that drill down through the GUI), you can debug this running the following code in Script Editor:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Image Capture"
        tell window "Image Capture"
            tell splitter group 1
                entire contents
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

This is slow, and produces a huge mass of text in the script log that shows every element of the GUI from `splitter group 1` on down. Search for 'Delete' in the log as I did in the image below: click the log button (circled in green), type command-F and enter the term 'delete' (circled in red), and it will show you the entry for the delete button. Then just copy that path into code.
[image]
You may need to change focus (i.e. put the `entire contents` line after the `window "Image Capture"` line to get a wider scope).

Note that the GUI may change as you add different devices and browse in different modes, and when the GUI changes all of the indexes (splitter group 1, group 2, button 7) might change as well. You may need to test this with a couple of different configurations if you use multiple devices to see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you. This does not for me, nor this form:   click button "Delete" of group 2 of splitter group 1 of window 1 of application process "Image Capture"

Comment: Thank you. Error message: System Events got an error: Can’t get group 2 of splitter group 1 of window "Image Capture" of process "Image Capture". Invalid index.

Comment: I can't debug this remotely, but I'll add some code above to show you how to debug it.